# Using SBT to load Datomic Pro peer library?

Tags: scala, sbt, datomic

Has anyone had any success with using SBT to download and manage the Datomic Pro peer library? Datomic's website gives clear instructions for Leiningen and Maven, but not SBT. Translating the Leiningen instructions, I came up with the following additions to my build.sbt file.

```
resolvers += "my.datomic.com" at "https://my.datomic.com/repo"

credentials += Credentials(realm = "restricted area",
                           host = "my.datomic.com",
                           userName = ...,
                           passwd = ...)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.datomic" % "datomic-pro" % "0.9.4752",
  ...
)
```

Note that I came up with the weird "restricted area" realm by running `curl -X GET https://my.datomic.com/repo/com/datomic/datomic-pro/0.9.4752/datomic-pro-0.9.4752.pom -v` and saw `WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="restricted area"`. That was the one piece of information that was not documented on the Datomic website.

Running the aforementioned build results in the dreaded UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES error.

```
[warn] ==== my.datomic.com: tried
[warn]   https://my.datomic.com/repo/com/datomic/datomic-pro/0.9.4752/datomic-pro-0.9.4752.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.datomic#datomic-pro;0.9.4752: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.datomic#datomic-pro;0.9.4752: not found
```

Note that the URL it's trying to download from is indeed correct. I can download the POM using wget and it works fine (supplying the user name and password, of course).

I should also mention that I'm using SBT 0.13.5-M2 Has anyone gotten this to work? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

As per Eugene's suggestion below, I tried running I tried running with `--debug` to see if I can get any additional info, but couldn't find any smoking gun. Output below:

```
[0m[[0mdebug[0m] [0m CLIENT ERROR: Not Found url=https://my.datomic.com/repo/com/datomic/datomic-pro/0.9.4752/datomic-pro-0.9.4752.pom[0m
[0m[[0mdebug[0m] [0m my.datomic.com: no ivy file found for com.datomic#datomic-pro;0.9.4752[0m
[0m[[33mwarn[0m] [0m module not found: com.datomic#datomic-pro;0.9.4752[0m
```

Comment: Could you try running it with log level bumped up to debug by `sbt --debug`? Sometimes JVM rejects https due to missing CA certs.

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thanks for the great suggestion. I tried running with the `--debug` flag, but couldn't find any smoking gun. I particularly didn't seen any stack traces or any text mentioning "cert." Do you happen to have an idea of anything specific that I should look for? Also, I forgot to mention in my original post that I'm using SBT 0.13.5-M2.

Comment: I don't have anything specific.

Comment: I thiiiink it might be that SBT/Ivy may be issuing a HEAD request, in which the Datomic server is incorrectly responding with a 404. Again doing a GET on the same exact URL works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my.datomic.com did not support HEAD requests. The Datomic folks have since fixed this.